# Second monitor connected by HDMI stopped receiving signal but Ubuntu 14.04 still shows that a second screen is connected

Tags: 14.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi

About 30 minutes ago I was watching something on my TV which is connected by HDMI to the port on my Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga running Ubuntu 14.04. For whatever reason now, the TV is no longer receiving a signal. When I look in the display portion of system settings though, Ubuntu still sees that a second display is connected and I can freely move my mouse onto this phantom display.

I would like to try and update my drivers for my intel graphics controller, shown here in the output to lspci -k, but intel seems to no longer support 14.04 and I can't seem to find the intel graphics installer for trusty anywhere.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2217
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I've tried restarting my computer with the TV on, but that doesn't change anything. Another point that may help is that I've recently reinstalled 14.04, and before I did so, the only way I could get Ubuntu to notice the second screen was by opening system settings. Immediately upon doing so (not even selecting the display tab, mind you), the second display sprang into action.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just passed trough the same problem today (Lenovo Thinkpad T430) after a system upgrade. I could see that selecting a lower resolution for the external monitor works for showing the extended desktop, but looked ugly, so I kept the default highest resolution on both laptop's screen and external monitor, then, I discovered that **disconnecting  all cables from the external monitor (power cable included) waiting ten seconds and reconnecting again worked just fine** and I have my two displays working as usual in extended desktop mode.